# Panniers for a Giant Defy 2.5 (2009)

Tags: panniers, rack

I was wondering whether anyone had any retrogradations for a lightweight rear pannier rack and a rack bag which would go on my Giant Defy 2.5 (2009).

I'm doing a 3 day cycle in a fortnight and will need to carry the bare essentials (i.e. toothbrush, travel wash, spare inners, jacket etc.

Thanks.

nick.

Answer (score 4):

Based on what I saw on the Giant Bicycle site, it looks like that model has braze-ons for attaching a standard rack - so just about any rack will work.  My personal favorite for light use (commuting and short tours) would be the [Blackburn EX-1](http://www.blackburndesign.com/racks_mirrors.html#ex_1).  If you need additional support for heavier loads there is a model with an extra support strut.

For the panniers, you have a ton of choices and need to weigh factors like size, materials, attachment mechanism, water resistance.

My favorite budget panniers are the house-brand bags put out by REI in the US.
[Novara Transfer Panniers](http://www.rei.com/product/780451)

For heavier use, better performance in wet weather, etc, I would recommend you look at bags by [Ortlieb](http://www.ortliebusa.com/cartgenie/prodList.asp?scat=6) and [Arkel](http://www.arkel-od.com/).

If you are really only carrying the bare essentials, and don't need the full packing volume you could use just one pannier, or you could use a 'rack trunk' that sits on top of the rick [similar to this one made by Arkel](http://www.arkel-od.com/us/all-categories/seat-bags-trunk-bags/tailrider.html), or the [Novara Commuter Rack Trunk](http://www.rei.com/product/780461).  My favorite is the Novara because of the side pockets that fold out and expand into mini-panniers.

Good luck with your tour.